# Problem inserting entities in database with @BeforeAll

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, h2

i'm trying to insert some entities in my H2 database to run some unit tests, for this im using a setup method decorated with the @BeforeAll annotation like so :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ItemRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepo; 
    
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository catRepo; 
        
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup(@Autowired ItemRepository itemRepo) {
        
        Category cat_0 = new Category(0L, "category_0");
        Category cat_1 = new Category(1L, "category_1");
        Category cat_2 = new Category(2L, "category_2");
        
        Item item_0 = new Item(0L, "item_0", "...", 7.99, "0000000000000", "imgUrl", Set.of(cat_0, cat_1));
        Item item_1 = new Item(1L, "item_1", "...", 8.99, "1111111111111", "imgUrl", Set.of(cat_2));        
        Item item_2 = new Item(2L, "item_2", "...", 9.99, "2222222222222", "imgUrl", Set.of(cat_0, cat_1, cat_2));  
        
        itemRepo.saveAll(List.of(item_0, item_1, item_2));
        
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public static void clean(@Autowired ItemRepository itemRepo, @Autowired CategoryRepository catRepo) {
        
        itemRepo.deleteAll();
        catRepo.deleteAll();
        
    }
        
    
    @Test
    public void items_should_have_been_saved() {
        
        List<Item> items = itemRepo.findAll();
        
        assertThat(items).hasSize(3);
        
    }
}
```

The '*items_should_have_been_saved*' Test fails (Expected size: 3 but was: 0), it seems my 'setup' method does not work, can anybody tell me what im doing wrong ? (I'm using SpringBoot 2.5.0)

src/test/resources/aplication.properties:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIG H2
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server.error.include-message=always
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>     
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Check what was going on with transactions in the logs. Maybe these inserts got rolled back. I use the Sql annotation to do my test data setup.

Comment: @NathanHughes You're right the transactions were rolled back, i added `@Rollback(value=false)` and now its not rolled back anymore but the problem still persist.